# datatable default sorting not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am using jquery datatable in my rails application. I want to add default order to a particular column. I have below jquery code for it,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample-table-2').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "pagingType": "simple",
            bJqueryUI: true,
            bServerSide: true,
      "aaSorting": [[ 4, "asc" ]], // 
            sAjaxSource: $('#sample-table-2').data('source'),
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "10%", "targets": column_count }
              ]
        })
        .on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
        .on('page', function () {setTimeout(function(){hideCellsOnMobile();},1000)} )
        .on( 'search.dt', function () {setTimeout(function(){hideCellsOnMobile();},1000)});
        $("table#sample-table-2").parent().addClass("no-padding")
});
```

But this default ordering is not getting applied.

Comment: Targets expects an array according to the docs, so you might want to try `{ "width": "10%", "targets": [ column_count] }`

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? Can you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample-table-2').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "pagingType": "simple",
            bJqueryUI: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            order: [[ 4, "asc" ]], // 
            sAjaxSource: $('#sample-table-2').data('source'),
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "10%", "targets": column_count }
              ]
        })
        .on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
        .on('page', function () {setTimeout(function(){hideCellsOnMobile();},1000)} )
        .on( 'search.dt', function () {setTimeout(function(){hideCellsOnMobile();},1000)});
        $("table#sample-table-2").parent().addClass("no-padding")
});
```